# exception overriding rules

Tags: java, overriding

Java overriding rules say that an overridden method can not throw a parent exception but this example is running fine. Can anybody shed some light on this?

```
public class TestA {
    public  void display() throws ArithmeticException{
        System.out.println("inside parent");
    }
}


public class Test extends TestA{
    public void display() throws RuntimeException{
     System.out.println("inside child");
   }
}
```

Comment: `RuntimeException` is unchecked, it does not need to be declared at all.

Answer (score 3):

In an overriding method, you are always allowed to declare that it throws a `RuntimeException`, because `RuntimeException`s are unchecked exceptions.  Usually methods aren't declared to throw `RuntimeException`s, but you can do so if you wish.

[Section 8.4.6 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.6) states:

> It is permitted but not required to mention unchecked exception classes (§11.1.1) in a throws clause.

Additionally, [Section 8.4.8.3 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3) states:

> For every checked exception type listed in the throws clause of m2, that same exception class or one of its supertypes must occur in the erasure (§4.6) of the throws clause of m1; otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.

But `RuntimeException` is unchecked, so it's not required to be in the superclass method's `throws` clause.

Answer (score 0):

`RuntimeException` are unchecked Exceptions and can be thrown from any method. Unlike checked Exception rules of method overriding do not apply here.